# Can't get Intel I210 ethernet working on Debian wheezy

Tags: networking, drivers, debian, intel

I have a server with an Asus P9D-I mainboard. It has two onboard Intel NICs:

```
# lspci -nn | grep Eth
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1533] (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1533] (rev 03)
```

The server is running Debian wheezy with the most recent backports kernel:

```
# cat /etc/debian_version
7.2

# uname -a
Linux hostname 3.10-0.bpo.3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.10.11-1~bpo70+1 (2013-09-24) x86_64 GNU/Linux

# dpkg -l | grep -E '(linux-image-amd64|linux-image-3.10)'
ii  linux-image-3.10-0.bpo.3-amd64          3.10.11-1~bpo70+1                   amd64        Linux 3.10 for 64-bit PCs
ii  linux-image-amd64                       3.10+52~bpo70+1                     amd64        Linux for 64-bit PCs (meta-package)
```

The ethernet interfaces *do* show up in `ifconfig -a`:

```
# ifconfig -a
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:22:0b:8b:30:a7  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Memory:dfe00000-dfe80000 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr ac:22:0b:8b:30:a8  
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Memory:dfd00000-dfd80000 
[...]
```

But for some reason, I can't actually use them for anything:

```
# ifconfig eth0 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such device
# ifconfig eth1 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: No such device
# ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
Cannot get device settings: No such device
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: No such device
Cannot get message level: No such device
Cannot get link status: No such device
No data available
# ethtool eth1
Settings for eth1:
Cannot get device settings: No such device
Cannot get wake-on-lan settings: No such device
Cannot get message level: No such device
Cannot get link status: No such device
No data available
```

`dmesg` doesn't seem to have any interesting output from the responsible `igb` driver:

```
# dmesg | grep igb
[    0.555167] igb: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Driver - version 5.0.3-k
[    0.555168] igb: Copyright (c) 2007-2013 Intel Corporation.
[    0.555669] igb 0000:01:00.0: irq 44 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.555674] igb 0000:01:00.0: irq 45 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.555679] igb 0000:01:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.555683] igb 0000:01:00.0: irq 47 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.555689] igb 0000:01:00.0: irq 48 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.599539] igb 0000:01:00.0: added PHC on eth0
[    0.599551] igb 0000:01:00.0: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
[    0.599553] igb 0000:01:00.0: eth0: (PCIe:2.5Gb/s:Width x1) ac:22:0b:8b:30:a7
[    0.599732] igb 0000:01:00.0: eth0: PBA No: 001300-000
[    0.599733] igb 0000:01:00.0: Using MSI-X interrupts. 4 rx queue(s), 4 tx queue(s)
[    0.600233] igb 0000:02:00.0: irq 50 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.600237] igb 0000:02:00.0: irq 51 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.600241] igb 0000:02:00.0: irq 52 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.600244] igb 0000:02:00.0: irq 53 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.600247] igb 0000:02:00.0: irq 54 for MSI/MSI-X
[    0.641792] igb 0000:02:00.0: added PHC on eth1
[    0.641794] igb 0000:02:00.0: Intel(R) Gigabit Ethernet Network Connection
[    0.641796] igb 0000:02:00.0: eth1: (PCIe:2.5Gb/s:Width x1) ac:22:0b:8b:30:a8
[    0.641853] igb 0000:02:00.0: eth1: PBA No: 001300-000
[    0.641854] igb 0000:02:00.0: Using MSI-X interrupts. 4 rx queue(s), 4 tx queue(s)
```

Does anyone know what could be going wrong here and how I can get these NICs working? If it's at all possible to do that without manually compiling kernels or drivers, I would prefer that.

Comment: The igb driver comes with a debug parameter, which you can set from 0 (no debug info) to 16 (all). You might try to set that to some low value, then report back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the cause - we had the `acpi-support` package installed which enables lots of unwanted power saving features due to a bug. Apparently the `igb` driver doesn't like those power save settings at all.

I've described the details in a bug report: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=728692

If anyone else encounters the problem: remove `acpi-support` and install `acpi-support-base`. The power button will still work, but all the remaining power saving magic of `acpi-support` that you don't want on a server is gone.

Answer (score 2):

Martin's solutions works fine - just make sure you install the back port kernel as the stable kernel does not support the Intel I210 NICs:

```
apt-get -t wheezy-backports install linux-image-amd64
```

this might take some time though.
Backporting details under back ports.debian.org